# Ionic 2: Provide data when setting root page

Tags: ionic2

Is there a way to provide data when setting the `rootPage` in Ionic 2?  I know I can provide data with the `NavController` like so:

```
this.navCtrl.push(NewPage, {
    foo: bar
})
```

but if I want to set a new `rootPage`, how can I pass data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set root page and pass the data like below:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(YourPage,{myData:"test data"})
```

then you can get this data in 'YourPage' like below:

```
this.navParam.get('myData')
```

Comment: i'm getting error "Error: No provider for NavController!"

Comment: Try rebuilding you app.

Answer (score 0):

in app.component.ts I have the following:

```
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  ...
```

so I can change the `rootPage` like so:

```
this.nav.push(NewPage, {
    foo: bar
})
```

rather than:

```
this.rootPage = NewPage;
```

and any data passed will be available in `NewPage`

Comment: If you do push then your page won't be the root page.

Comment: Prerak Tiwari's answer is the correct one. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it added a very useful piece of new information for me: the ability to inject `Nav` into `MyApp` base component!

Answer (score 0):

Pop a page off of the navigation stack:

```
this.navCtrl.pop();
```

To change the root page at any point throughout the application:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(SecondPage);
```

Passing Data to root page:

```
this.navCtrl.push(SecondPage, {
        thing1: data1,
        thing2: data2
});
```